# 14 LTS, /usr/bin suid flags, looking for an offical developer

Tags: permissions, lts, development

My first goof in 5 year using Ubuntu, but a big one.

Trying to get strongloop working, I chowned /usr/bin to my user account, and back to root ( only to realize a bit later that by doing so I erased suid and sgid flag. The first thing i noticed was that my x11 didn't start again, do I did a general `sudo chown s+u /usr/bin/x*` as a quick and dirty fix.

But I fear or to be correct know for sure that there will be other file/links in there who need the same flag. ( I already fixed sudo )
So I need a detailed list, preferable from an Ubuntu developer.

I know this question has been answered before here, but the list posted looks incomplte as it lacks x11.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of asking a dev for a list of package, maybe you can ask your system to restore the permissions of installed packages to their original state ?

To get a list of installed packages, you can use the following command :

`dpkg --get-selections | grep "install" | grep -v "deinstall"`

you can then use `apt-get install --reinstall <package>`, which will reset the package's files permissions.

If you want to do that for all your packages in one command, you can try:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall $(dpkg --get-selections | grep "install" | grep -v "deinstall" | cut -f1 | xargs)`

Comment: I have been thinking about that, but I prefer to do it by using a list, when I tried to use aptitude to remove and reinstall x11 it suggested to uninstall almost everything on my system. I'm going to try apt-get --reinstall.